# How to access files under role/files on remote host

Tags: ansible

I have a situation that I have somecustom scripts which are too long/complex to convert to ansible tasks so i am trying to run them with ansible shell module. But role_path or playbook_dir
variables have the values on the controller nodes paths not the paths on the remote hosts.
How can i access from shell module to files directory under role path.

Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what you want to do? Normally there is no `roles` directory on the remote. If you want the files directory on the controller node, it's just `{{ role_path }}/files/` and you could pass this as a CLI argument to your script.

Answer (score 0):

Use [script](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/script_module.html) module. Store your script file inside `files` directory of role with name `script-file` and below task will work

```
- name: Execute scipt on remote host
  script: <script-file>
  args:
    arg1: val1
    arg2: val2
  register: out 
- name: name: Print output
  debug:
    msg: "{{out.stdout}}"
```